# need an example of a specific recursion function

Tags: recursion

I needed an example of a program or procedure that has this kind of function call routine.

```
f1() call f2()
f2() call f3()
f3() call f1()
```

This procedure will make some kind of recursion and I was wondering if there is any program that use this method in its build.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what language? And what is the base case for this recursion (when the function ends and return back)? Also why not just have a controller that makes these calls one after another in a while loop?

Comment: I dont want the actual source code so no specific language, just want an algorithm example of a program. And about the loop I heard if used in recursion it would cause problems like infinity loop

Comment: Well you still need to specify more details about what you mean exactly by these function calls. And what causes the recursion to end?

Comment: Well I just have this pattern that f1 have to call f2, f2 gotta call f3 and so on then f3 call back f1 and make a recursion somhow

Comment: I understand the pattern, but what causes the pattern to end? If `f3()` calls `f1()` then it will be an endless loop and the program will never exit. Recursion requires a base case, just like a while loop requires an end condition or break from the loop.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem

Comment: So then what are you asking? If you have this endless pattern you need some condition or case where the pattern is going to end.

Comment: Do you have any idea about it? I mean have you seen any algorithm like this with a base case?

Comment: Yes in fact every recursive algorithm has a base case. The base case is dependent on what you are doing in the functions. It could be time based, input based, or based on a condition in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want some functions to call other functions one after another then call the next function at the end of its execution. Although if it is not required for each function to pass information down it would be better to call them individually with a while loop on the outside calling them.

Below is code in Python demonstrating the calls:

```
def f1():
    # Sample base case based on input
    if (input("Enter x to stop: ") == 'x'):
        return

    # Do something
    f2()  # Calls f2

def f2():
    # Do something
    f3()  # Calls f3

def f3():
    # Do something
    f1() # Repeats the pattern recursively

f1() # starts pattern
```

However, each recursive call has to be stored into memory and can create a stack overflow. So it is probably better to make this an interative call like so:

```
def f1():
    # Do something

def f2():
    # Do something

def f3():
    # Do something

# Repeats pattern calling each function
while True:
    # Sample base case based on input
    if (input("Enter x to stop: ") == 'x'):
        break

    f1()
    f2()
    f3()
```

Comment: And one last thing: Do you know any program that use this method? I just want the name and a little expresion about what it does?

Comment: Nope I don't know any specific ones that do. I know that merge sort and some binary search tree algorithms use recursive function calls that can probably help with understanding.